# how to make choice between two primary keys 1 will null if other has value?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

this is my code for table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product] (
    [prod_Id]   NUMERIC (5)  NULL,
    [barcode]   NUMERIC (13)  NULL,
    [prod_name] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [price]     FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [stock]     NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [cat_id]    NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [discount]  FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([prod_Id],[barcode] ASC)
);
```

I have 2 primary keys `prod_id` and `barcode`. I want to make them null as user have choice either to enter `prod_id` or `barcode`. Both will not have value at same time. Now please anyone help me how to do it. I tried to make them null it gives syntax error.

Comment: Primary Key should be unique and not Null.

Comment: Prod_Id and Barcode are defined as null, you wont be allowed to create primary key on nullable columns.

Comment: Create an identity column as a rowid field and set it to primary. Use non-clustered index over prod_id and barcode if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace primary key with unique

```
unique CLUSTERED ([prod_Id],[barcode] ASC)
```

(or)

Give some default value to the columns that are there in the composite primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product] (
    [prod_Id]   NUMERIC (5) default 0,
    [barcode]   NUMERIC (13) default 0,
    [prod_name] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [price]     FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [stock]     NUMERIC (18)  NULL,
    [cat_id]    NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [discount]  FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([prod_Id],[barcode] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `C#` and sending data from `C#` to `SQL` server then then you can have validation in place to check if 1 is null then other one must be not null and throw exception/error from there and make both the columns in DB as Unique not primary key. It might help.

Answer (score 1):

In any database table, there is one and only one primary key and that primary key should not be null.
In your case, for each prod_id there will be unique barcode and vise versa. So, it won't make any sense making any one of this as NULL.
instead create 2 table, one containing table_id and other containing barcode and then refer one in another using foreign_key.